# Render report quality EMF versus PDF

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I'm having difficulties rendering a SSRS serverreport and printing it from code.

Although rendering succeeds and the report is printed, the results in quality in the graphics are poor. The report itself has a high res 6kx1k GIF image for the logo.

I've made image below to illustrate the difference between rendering using EMF versus PDF:

[image: (PDF on the left, EMF on the right)]

As you can see the font look great (no pixallation) and when rendering in PDF logo look good. However the EMF version has poor quality as you can see on the edges in the logo.

Anyone came across this and solved it?

I'm running SQL Server 2008R2 SP2 (10.50.4000)

Code to render the report using EMF

```
public List<byte[]> Render()
{
    // Setting credentials and reporting services uri
    ReportExecutionService reportService = new ReportExecutionService
        {
            Credentials = _credentials,
            Url = Settings.Default.ReportingService
        };

    // Prepare report parameter.
    ExecutionHeader execHeader = new ExecutionHeader();
    reportService.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader;
    reportService.LoadReport(_report, null);
    reportService.SetExecutionParameters(_parameters.ToArray(), "en-us");

    // Render
    bool startup = true;
    List<byte[]> streams = new List<byte[]>();
    int numberOfPages = 0;
    byte[] result = null;
    while (startup || result.Length > 0)
    {
        startup = false;
        string devInfo = String.Format(@"<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat><PrintDpiX>150</PrintDpiX><PrintDpiY>150</PrintDpiY><StartPage>{0}</StartPage></DeviceInfo>", numberOfPages + 1);
        string encoding, mimeType, extension;
        string[] streamIDs = null;
        Warning[] warnings = null;
        result = reportService.Render("IMAGE", devInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);

        if (result.Length > 0)
        {
            streams.Add(result);
        }
        numberOfPages++;
    }
    return streams;
}
```

Here's the printdocument implementation

```
public class PrintReport : PrintDocument
{
    private int _currentPage;
    private  List<byte[]> _pages;

    public PrintReport()
    {
    }

    public List<byte[]> Pages
    {
        get { return _pages; }
        set { _pages = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnBeginPrint(PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnBeginPrint(e);
        _currentPage = 0;
    }

    protected override void OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPrintPage(e);

        Stream pageToPrint = new MemoryStream(_pages[_currentPage]);
        pageToPrint.Position = 0;

        // Load each page into a Metafile to draw it.
        using (Metafile pageMetaFile = new Metafile(pageToPrint))
        {
            Rectangle adjustedRect = new Rectangle(
                    e.PageBounds.Left - (int)e.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
                    e.PageBounds.Top - (int)e.PageSettings.HardMarginY,
                    e.PageBounds.Width,
                    e.PageBounds.Height);

            // Draw a white background for the report
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect);

            // Draw the report content
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pageMetaFile, adjustedRect);

            // Prepare for next page.  Make sure we haven't hit the end.
            _currentPage++;
            e.HasMorePages = _currentPage < _pages.Count;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnQueryPageSettings(QueryPageSettingsEventArgs e)
    {
        e.PageSettings = (PageSettings)PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the logo image type in the report? In the past I've had poor image rendering in PDF exports and changing the image to a jpeg from a png solved this... This may not be applicable in your case, especially since your PDF seems to be the the good one, but it may be worth trying different image file types to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Ian I'm actually using high resolution (6kx1k) GIF files for the logo. The logo has only two colors and no shading. Would have used a vector based image if it were available. Did try PNG first but that didn't work out as good as GIF.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "150" with the desired dpi in the snippet below copied from devInfo, it should help. Changing it to "300" solved my similar issue.

```
<PrintDpiX>150</PrintDpiX><PrintDpiY>150</PrintDpiY>
```

Note that it can be frustrating to change this in your reports as the report viewer rendering engine will still show with 150 dpi when previewing your reports, so you will need to test your layouts using your code for testing after each update to the rdl.